# How to create new LinkedIn app style ActionBar with Tabs inside it?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm trying to create an ActionBar with 5 tabs and a button/imageview that will open NavigationDrawer from the right side. Very similar to what LinkedIn have done in their new Android application, here is an image:

[image]

I tried two methods, but non of them went well for me:

1. I tried to created a new TabbedActivity project, the resulted layout included this:

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       android:id="@+id/main_content"                                                    
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools
       android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       tools:context="com.emildesign.linkedinstyleactionbar.MainActivity">
       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
           android:id="@+id/fab"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
           android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

Now I tried to remove ToolBar from here and set AppBarLayout orientation as horizontal in order to add to the action bar another icon for opening the drawer. But the AppBarLayout can't have horizontal orientation. So this solutions does not works.

2. Another way I tried to implement it is using an AppCompat with ActionBar and ActionBar.Tab. as it looks like it was created by LinkedIn when I looked at this layout using the AI Automator, using the following code:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
   // of the app.
   mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   // Set up the action bar.
   final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

   // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
   // parent.
   actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

   // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
   actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

   // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
   // user swipes between sections.
   mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
   mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
           // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
           // Tab.
           actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
       }
   });

   // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
   for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
       // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
       // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
       // listener for when this tab is selected.
       actionBar.addTab(
               actionBar.newTab()
                       .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                       .setTabListener(this));
   }
   }
   ```

but I could not reach the desired result. Has someone created something like this and can give me a push in the right direction?

**Result:** provided by Vikram answer works great and this is its result in landscape mode:

[image]

Portrait works as expected as well.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/Mirkoddd/TabBarView)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the first option with the `TabLayout` placed *inside* the `Toolbar`? This is what I get by doing so:

[image]

Layout side:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Activity side:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
....
....
tabLayout.getTabAt(5).setIcon(R.drawable.icon6);
```

You can also do without `CoordinatorLayout`, along with `AppBarLayout`, since they do not come into play. `layout_scrollFlags` & `layout_behavior` will go as well.

**Edit:**

I used UI Automator Viewer to check what LinkedIn was doing with their layout. They are not using an `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`. Instead, they have a horizontal `LinearLayout` with `TabLayout` as the first child, and a couple of independent icons as the second and third.

Next, I checked `TabLayout's` source to determine the exact layout that tabs use. `TabLayout's` tabs are defined by `TabLayout.TabView` which is a `LinearLayout` created programmatically:

```
class TabView extends LinearLayout implements OnLongClickListener {
    ....
}
```

I translated this to XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: The dimensions assigned above are not arbitrary. They are defined in the design support library.

So, the final `ActionBar` layout will be:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon6"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that at the left side of the ToolBar, there is an empty space, while it's not existing in the right side. So the tabs come out uneven.

Comment: Another issue with this solutions is that except the tabs I need to add another icon for the drawer layout and make it the size of a tab. which is very problematic in this case.

Comment: @EmilAdz The empty space is governed by `contentInsetStart` under the style attr `toolbarStyle`. By default, it is set to `16dp`, and can be changed to `0dp` to remove the space on the left...

Comment: Yes, I found it already. but I have a really big problem to add another two imageviews at the end of the toolbar that would have the same width as the other tabs. As it works in the LinkedIn app.

Comment: Right I want to create exactly what they did with their action bar. but the difference between what they did and you preposal is that here all the tool bar is populated with tabs. LinkedIn app has two image view at the end of the tool bar that do not work as tabs, but as usual buttons. As a result the selected tab indicator do not slide to those two images. And this is exactly what I need to implement.

Comment: @EmilAdz My understanding of your question was that you need a layout _similar_ to the LinkedIn app (with tabs visually residing inside the `ActionBar`) - but not exactly. Since you're trying to recreate that layout, we can use UIAutomatorView to see what LinkedIn have done. My suspicion is that they've left out the `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` altogether and used a horizontal `LinearLayout` acting as the `ActionBar`. Inside this `LinearLayout`, the `TabLayout` goes first with `layout_weight=1`. Then comes the toggle `ImageButton` with weight zero. I'll confirm this in a few minutes.

Comment: why don't you think that they did exactly what you describe with the LinearLayout and the TabLayout but with the Toolbar? I tried the game with the weights exactly as you said. The image button in this case results in a smaller size.

Comment: @EmilAdz That's probably because you used the `ImageButtons` themselves. We should look at how `TabLayout` defines its `Tabs`, and then try to duplicate their layout. I'll post an update to my answer above.

Comment: @EmilAdz I have added an edit to my answer. `why don't you think that they did exactly what you describe with the LinearLayout and the TabLayout but with the Toolbar? ` ... Because `Toolbar` doesn't have the concept of `layout_weights`. UIAutomatorViewer confirmed this.

Comment: Thanks you for your great work and your explanatory answer. the only issue I left with your code is that for some reason, in landscape mode the tabs are not spread all over the TabLayout space but centered in the middle with much small padding than it should. Do you know how can this fixed?

Comment: @EmilAdz Yes of course! If you browse to where your SDK is installed locally, open up `<SDK>/extras/android/support/design/res/values/styles.xml`, and find the style `Widget.Design.TabLayout`, you'll see `<item name="tabGravity">fill</item>`. Note that this gravity value is good since our layout is as required in portrait mode. Next, check `res/values-land/styles.xml`. Under `Widget.Design.TabLayout`, `tabGravity` has the value `center`. We need to change this.

Comment: @EmilAdz In your project's `res/values/styles.xml`, add a style, say `MyTabLayoutStyle`. Its parent style will be `Widget.Design.TabLayout` and the only attribute we will override is `tabGravity`: `<item name="tabGravity">fill</item>`. Lastly, we'll set this style on our TabLayout in xml: `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout .... style="@style/MyTabLayoutStyle" ..../>`. I haven't tried this myself. So, I am curious as to if it will work. if it does work, please let me know, and I'll add this to the answer for completion sake.

Comment: Wow, Thanks you very much for your enormous and for bearing with me. The solution you provided for the landscape works great. I did it exactly as you described it: with the style, and the result is exactly as in the LinkedIn app. I'm accepting/upvoting the answer. Again, Thank you very much. I also added an image to the question that you can provide for you answer.

Comment: Please provide your comments as part of the answer, for future readers. Thanks.