# How to make 4 Tabs and 2 ImageView's in ToolBar equal in size?

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar, android-tablayout

I have created the following XML layout. You can see that in it I have a ToolBar that contains a LinearLayout with 3 view in it: a TabLayout and 2 imageview. I want to set the width of each image view as the width of each Tab inside the resulted TabLayout, so that it would appear as if I have 6 tabs with same size but two of them should not be tabs.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/tab_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tab1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tab1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

**What I have done:** Now as you can see in the layout I tried to reach the desired result with weights in the LinearLayout. but the result is unsatisfying. And I have no other idea how to perform this.

**The question:** Has someone done something like this and can provide some input on this matter?

Comment: You might try creating six tabs, setting your ImageViews as custom Views on the last two.

Comment: @MikeM. But in this case the selected tab indicator would slide to those two tabs as well, and this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: You could toggle the indicator in the `OnTabSelectedListener`, using `TabLayout#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor()` and `TabLayout#setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight()`, depending on which tab is currently selected.

Comment: Yeah, actually, just toggling the color to transparent and back seems to work nicely, for me at least.

Comment: @MikeM., Testing this solution right now, If it will work nicely for me as well I will let you know.

Comment: Oops, maybe not. I just noticed that the indicator reappears under the custom tabs before it slides to a regular tab.

Comment: @MikeM. do you maybe have other ideas regarding this? or the original question?

Comment: What was unsatisfactory about your posted layout? Bad sizing?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, the images do not get the same width size as the tabs do.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'd have to play around with it a bit.

Comment: @MikeM., well if you want to, I would love the help. more over this question is connected to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048271/how-to-create-new-linkedin-app-style-actionbar-with-tabs-inside-it that has bounty on it. So if you find a solution I can grant you a lot of points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use TabLayout as following:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_weight="4"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon5"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon6"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And populate it using the following code:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); 
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager); 

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon1); 
....  
tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.icon6);
```

The complete solution can be found here:

[How to create new LinkedIn app style ActionBar with Tabs inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048271/how-to-create-new-linkedin-app-style-actionbar-with-tabs-inside-it)